# javascript read huge json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance, object

Hi I have a huge json object(about 1500line) that I want to get some info

```
{
    level1:{
        ...
        level2{
        ....
            level3{
                ....
                level4{
                    prop1:value1,
                    prop2:value2,
                    prop3:value3            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To read the object I have the following code

```
for(var key in prodOfferObj){
   var prodOffLvl1 = prodOfferObj[key];
   var prodOfferKey1 = key;

   for(var param in prodOffLvl1){
     var itemDescription=prodOffLvl1[param];
        for(var j= 0, itemsLen=itemDescription.length; j<itemsLen; j++){
           var item = itemDescription[j];
           if(item.label ==='someValue'){.....}
....
```

I would like to get the value1 if value2 is a certain string.

I would like to avoid interate over the object because it is huge and in a previous step I already read this object, but stopped at level3.

The only way is interate over all the object again? The main point of this question is to get a good performance / practice and feel like the development effort it's huge.

Thanks

Comment: add real object and show what you have tried

Comment: If you know the names of the levels, you can just refer to the correct level directly: `if (typeof jsonObject[level1][level2][level3][level4].prop2 === 'string') {return jsonObject[level1][level2][level3][level4].prop1;}`

Comment: Have you got some working code that does what you want but exhibits a performance problem, or is this a theoretical problem that might not actually exist?

Comment: You have to iterate...show what you tried. Nobody will write this for you without seeing some effort on your part and some realistic data

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes it's more a theoretical question because the code works.

Comment: If it works question is more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @peterK But does it work _quickly enough_, or is it exhibiting performance issues?  If it's quick enough, move on - spend your time building more functionality :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe The performance is no big deal. I just feel that the development effort is too big.

Comment: @peterK Ah ok, in that case - charlietfl's suggestion of [codereview.se] is probably appropriate - just ensure you review their [how to ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page, as snippets of code won't be enough

Comment: @JamesThorpe OK Thanks. Yes I have to try the charliefl and Shilly suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the previous item during your iteration so you don't need to start over again.  I think this is what you are looking for.

```
for(var param in prodOffLvl1){
    var itemDescription=prodOffLvl1[param];
    var prev = null;
    for(var j= 0, itemsLen=itemDescription.length; j<itemsLen; j++){
        var item = itemDescription[j];
        if(item.label ==='someValue'){.....}
            if (prev !== null) { // remember, the first one has no previous
                console.log('I found value2, I want:', prev);
            }
        }
    }

    prev = item;
}
```